# Respostas que apenas contêm links são boas?

Tags: suporte, proposta-para-faq, qualidade, apenas-link

Algumas respostas são colocadas praticamente como um apontador para outro recurso externo. É apenas um link e uma frase, algumas vezes dizendo o que tem link, outras nem isso.

Chamamos essas respostas de *link-only*. Porque elas não são consideradas de boa qualidade?

Veja também a [ajuda oficial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)